# Push Notification Testing Workflow [iOS]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I have hit a dilemma and don't know how to go about this problem.

I have an application right now being tested by a good amount of people. Within this app, I have push notifications set up. No problem with them at all. Everything is going great.

I hit a problem when I want to test versions that are in build currently. If I send a push notification to test certain features, they get sent to everyone currently with the app. Yes, it makes sense. But how do I go about setting up a workflow where I am able to have separate push notifications for live versions of the app and pre-release versions?

I use Parse for the push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [advanced targeting](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#push-notifications-using-advanced-targeting). Just enumerate device tokens you need to send push notifications to in `where` clause. Check out [this](https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-push-to-a-list-of-device-tokens-without-using-channels) sample in parse.com forum.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding this. When I go to push, I choose segment. Within segment it comes up wit something called _Installation Conditions_ . Underneath that I am given many different options such as, GCMSenderID, appIdentifier, appVersion, appName, badge, channels, createdAt, parseVersion, pushType, timeZone, updateAt. Those are what is given. I am in the wrong area for this?

Comment: This is for google push services. You need to build a query that contains an array of tokens in `where` clause.

Comment: where would I build this query? Or place it?

Comment: There is a lot of good documentation on parse.com, have you read it? [This](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) tutorial covers all the options to send push notifications. You are able to do that via command line on your machine using curl. You are able to do it in [cloud code](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications). Choose an option that fit your needs best.

Comment: that makes so much more sense! Thank you. I will read the documentation in depth. Just one little understanding you cleared up.